# Filtering zero values only if both columns are zero

Tags: sql, excel

I need the table to exclude rows where rw.amount <> 0 AND rw.paid_subs <> 0 but still include any row that has values in either column.

I am rather clueless with SQL tables, so I have been blindly guessing at how to code this.

```
AND rw.amount <> 0 
AND rw.paid_subs <> 0
```

Comment: Any null values in those columns?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct, but using DeMorgan's Laws we can rewrite your exclusion logic as:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE amount = 0 OR paid_subs = 0;
```